# How to retrieve contact image URL in CiviCRM with the API

Tags: drupal, api, contact-image

I'm trying to retrieve contact with the below api call

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
  "return": ["image_URL","first_name","last_name"]
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

but my image url is always empty despite having an image on my contacts profile. This is what the response looks like

```
"is_error": 0,
"version": 3,
"count": 5,
"values": {
    "1": {
        "contact_id": "1",
        "image_URL": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "contact_is_deleted": "0",
        "id": "1"
    },
    "2": {
        "contact_id": "2",
        "image_URL": "",
        "first_name": "AdminJoshua",
        "last_name": "AdminAroke",
        "contact_is_deleted": "0",
        "id": "2"
    },
    "3": {
        "contact_id": "3",
        "image_URL": "",
        "first_name": "Joshua",
        "last_name": "Aroke",
        "contact_is_deleted": "0",
        "id": "3"
    },
    "4": {
        "contact_id": "4",
        "image_URL": "",
        "first_name": "Oluwajuwon",
        "last_name": "Aroke",
        "contact_is_deleted": "0",
        "id": "4"
    },
    "5": {
        "contact_id": "5",
        "image_URL": "",
        "first_name": "Ogirima",
        "last_name": "Aroke",
        "contact_is_deleted": "0",
        "id": "5"
    }
}
}
```

I have been trying to put this to work. I'm using drupal 7 and I have profile image set on my contact. Please, let me know what to do right

Comment: Hi, Olyjosh, just tried this on the demo CiviCRM (4.7.17)  instance and it works fine. I use the API explorer (See http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api#explorer). What is your version of CiviCRM? Does image_URL work when you call the API with the explorer or with Drush?

Comment: My version of CiviCRM is CiviCRM 4.7.16.
The above json print is from the api explorer

Comment: Try to reproduce the situation on the demo instance. If it works, search for a difference on your local installation.

Comment: I just edited the demo instance and uploaded an image to the instance here [http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/user/2/edit](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/user/2/edit) and I use the api explorer [http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api#explorer](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api#explorer)  to query drush like this   

drush cvapi Contact.get sequential=1 id=202. 

**Behold, It's the same thing, the image element is empty too.**

Comment: The image_URL returned by the API is the image that is attached to the CiviCRM contact, not to the drupal user. You can upload an image of a contact by selecting edit and upload a file with "Browse/Upload Image" in the first section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image_URL returned by the API is the image that is attached to the CiviCRM contact, not to the Drupal user. You can upload an image of a contact by selecting edit and upload a file with "Browse/Upload Image" in the first section.

Answer (score 0):

This works (tested after attaching an image to a contact on the demo site):

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "return": ["image_URL","first_name","last_name","email"],
  "image_URL": {"IS NOT NULL":1}
}).done(function(result) {
  // Debug first image URL retrieved:
  console.log(result.values[0].image_URL);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following API call returned image_url

`$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'return' => "image_URL",
  'id' => CONTACT_ID,
));`

Response looks like this:

`{
    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 1,
    "id": xxxxxx,
    "values": [
        {
            "contact_id": "xxxxxx",
            "image_URL": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/civicrm/contact/imagefile?photo=Img1_ca0063c865d7fe65019be27dd071258c.png",
            "id": "xxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}`